# RandomAccessFile setLength() writes 0 for large gigabyte values

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I am attempting to write files using the RandomAccessFile.setLength() method. The problem I'm running into is: ***it works fine for some file sizes but not others.***

Wild guess: I'm not sure if it has something to do with my RAM (16GB)? AFAIK it seems to be failing for large GB values which are multiples of 8.

If anyone knows why this is actually occurring that would be the best answer.

I included a toy program which should demonstrate this behavior. Let me know if you're seeing the same results.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Debug {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // create 5 file sizes: 16 KB, 16 MB, 8GB, 16 GB, 30 GB
    long KILO = 1024;
    long testNum1 = KILO * 16;               // 16 KB
    long testNum2 = KILO * KILO * 16;        // 16 MB
    long testNum3 = KILO * KILO * KILO * 8;  //  8 GB
    long testNum4 = KILO * KILO * KILO * 16; // 16 GB
    long testNum5 = KILO * KILO * KILO * 30; // 30 GB

    // print the 5 file sizes
    System.out.println("testNum1 is " + testNum1 + " bytes");
    System.out.println("testNum2 is " + testNum2 + " bytes");
    System.out.println("testNum3 is " + testNum3 + " bytes");
    System.out.println("testNum4 is " + testNum4 + " bytes");
    System.out.println("testNum5 is " + testNum5 + " bytes");

    // attempt to write 5 files to disk, using these sizes
    RandomAccessFile f = null;
    try {
      f = new RandomAccessFile("testNum1", "rw"); // <-- PASS
      f.setLength( testNum1 );
      f = new RandomAccessFile("testNum2", "rw"); // <-- PASS
      f.setLength( testNum2 );
      f = new RandomAccessFile("testNum3", "rw"); // <-- FAIL
      f.setLength( testNum3 );
      f = new RandomAccessFile("testNum4", "rw"); // <-- FAIL
      f.setLength( testNum4 );
      f = new RandomAccessFile("testNum5", "rw"); // <-- PASS
      f.setLength( testNum5 );
    } catch( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
      if( f != null ) {
        try {
          f.close();
        } catch( IOException e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it works fine for some file sizes but not others`? What do you expect to happen? You're not writing anything to the files.

Comment: When you run the program: 16KB, 16MB, and 30GB all get written to the disk, but 8GB and 16GB do not.

Comment: What happens if you delete the files and then try to create only the 8GB and 16GB files?

Comment: I am still seeing them as 0 bytes.

Comment: I think I found out what is happening, but I can't answer my own question yet due to being a new user at StackOverflow. Strangely, the file sizes are showing up as 8GB and 16GB in [Windows Explorer](http://i.imgur.com/DlTvgOM.png) and [CMD prompt](http://i.imgur.com/bMlnHqb.png) but not in the MinGW32 Git Bash prompt (the MinGW screenshot in the OP).